# pdf button is not showing in datatable in angular 6.9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, excel, pdf

I used node version v10.16.3 and npm version is 6.9.0. excel, csv button is showing but pdf buttons are not showing

> ```
>  "styles": [
>           "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
>           "src/assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
>           "node modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css",
>           "src/assets/css/style.css"
>           ],
> "scripts": [
>           "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
>           "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
>           "src/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js",
>           "src/assets/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
>           "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js",
>           "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
>           "src/assets/js/script.js"
>           ]
> ```

Comment: you'll need to add a lot more clarity to your question - currently it makes no sense

Comment: yes, add some code, maybe the code where the button is supposed to appear